# Kendo UI datepicker, changes date when choosing time- PLEASE anyone

Tags: jquery, datetime, user-interface, datepicker, kendo-ui

I have two documents using the jquery - Kendo UI date picker. One is working fine as I want but the other one has this problem.

When I choose first the date, the date is shown perfectly in the button and calculated and I can choose time without changing the date.. http://pixelfreaks.dk/waterout/klippfiks-sluttid.html (this one works fine, I can change date and time without changing both fields...

BUT in the other document it does not work.. I have tried so very much. I have tried to copy just the text variables to calculate. When choosing the date and then the time the date is changed every time the date is changed. The only difference should be the hours I calculate with. http://pixelfreaks.dk/waterout/klippfisk-starttid.html (this is the wrong one)

Can anyone please help me find the problem. Document 1 is working fine. I choose the date and then the time.

Document 2: has a script that have some other hours for couting results in the button. I have tried moving some of the code over from document 1 but I can´t see what to do. Hope anyone can help me I can´t see whats wrong

The files they are using are the same. The only changes things are numbers for calculating the time

Comment: Welcome to SO!  Can you edit your question to include the code that isn't working?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `e.sender.value()` gives you a *pointer* to the date not a copy. When you change its value you are actually changing the value also for the displayed data.

You should make a copy of it, you can use:

```
function closeDateTimePicker(e) {
    var edate = new Date(e.sender.value());
    edate.setHours(edate.getHours()+8);
    $("#Shift1").text(edate.toLocaleString());
    edate.setHours(edate.getHours()+16);
    $("#Shift2").text(edate.toLocaleString());
    edate.setHours(edate.getHours()+24);
    $("#Shift3").text(edate.toLocaleString());
};
```

In your original code there was no problem because the result of adding dates are actually the original date since you start subtracting and then you add. Here since you only add you end up in a different date.

Check it here: http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/zA9r5/